# How do I update a property on the model based on the user selection?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need to update the expiration date based on the action by the user. I want to handle this in the javascript if possible instead of sending a hidden field back to the controller.

In the model I have two dates.

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
```

In the form, I show the current expiration date and this drop down select box

```
                <div class="controls col-md-6">
                    <label for="selExpirationPeriod">Select the expiration period</label>
                </div>
                <div class="controls col-md-6">
                    <select id="selExpirationPeriod" class="form-control">
                        <option value=30>30 days</option>
                        <option value=90>90 days</option>
                        <option value=182>Half year</option>
                        <option value=365 selected>Year</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

The goal is to update the expiration date with the period chosen.

I have this routine where I want to make the change, on clicking the Update button.

```
function updateModel() {

    alert($('#ExpirationDate'));
    return true;
}
```

Instead of showing the expiration date, it shows "[object Object]"

I need something like

```
model.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today + $selExpirationPeriod.value
```

I don't know how to access any of those three from javascript.

Summary: ExpirationDate is a property of the model which will be persisted in the database after it gets back to the server. I'd prefer to handle the calculation in the client if I can, just because I don't know how. It seems like it ought to be simple and I ought to learn it.

**Update**
Resolved. I had to add the hidden field so I could send the value back. As display only, it doesn't get returned.

```
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls col-md-6">
                @Html.HiddenFor(cm => cm.ExpirationDate, new { id = "ExpirationDate" }) @*hidden input so that POST will send the data back*@
                @Html.LabelFor(cm => cm.ExpirationDate)
                @Html.DisplayFor(cm => cm.ExpirationDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then I had to update the field from the routine.

```
    document.getElementById("ExpirationDate").value = expireDate;
```

Comment: Are you want to update server-side property based from selected date option in `<select>` element and passed it back to view inside an element? I think you can use AJAX by handling `change` event then setting `model.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(x)`, but you need to provide relevant server-side codes and explain your objectives further.

Comment: I added a summary of what I'm trying to accomplish. If it isn't possible, then I'll just add another property to the model and pass it back that way. No need to complicate things with another call just to pass one property.

Comment: The `$('#ExpirationDate')` in the `alert($('#ExpirationDate'));` is the jQuery object for the `#ExpirationDate` element. If you want to get its value, you might need to do `alert($('#ExpirationDate').val());`

Comment: @BWhite, is your problem solved ? what is your opinion about the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wand calculate the expire date based on user selection of `selExpirationPeriod` and from what you want something like `model.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today + $selExpirationPeriod.value` you should add that days number to your date

I have provided pure JavaScript extension named `addDaysToDate()` to add day number to `DateTime.Now` as sample you can improve it, any way in `expBtn` click you have `expireDate` you can pass it to server by that Ajax.

```js
Date.prototype.addDaysToDate = function(days) { 
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}  
var expBtn = document.getElementById('makeExpDate');
expBtn.addEventListener("click",function(e){
   var option = document.getElementById("selExpirationPeriod");
   var selectedDay = option.options[option.selectedIndex].value;
   var date = new Date(); 
   var expireDate = date.addDaysToDate(selectedDay);
   alert(expireDate);
},false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls col-md-6">
    <label for="selExpirationPeriod">Select the expiration period</label>
    </div>
    <div class="controls col-md-6">
    <select id="selExpirationPeriod" class="form-control">
      <option value=30>30 days</option>
      <option value=90>90 days</option>
      <option value=182>Half year</option>
      <option value=365 selected>Year</option>
     </select>
</div>
<button id='makeExpDate'>Expire Date</button>
```

Comment: Interestingly, selecting 365 gives a result of '6/22/2025'. Turns out that it is interpreting the 365 as a string. Days + 0 = 3650. So that was easily fixed once we found it.

Comment: This one got me most of the way there, so I marking it as the answer.

Comment: Yeah it may have some little problems, I am glad it helped you to find the clue.

Answer (score 0):

> You are not able to update server side property on client side. you have to make an ajax call to update Expiration date field or etc.

Comment: That sounds perfectly reasonable and I would believe you except that we are updating every other field in the model. This is the UpdateClient form. It seems like I update the property on the model somehow and post it back to the controller.

Comment: yeah you are write but he mention in question 
I need something like
model.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today + $selExpirationPeriod.value so i answer acordingly

Answer (score 0):

The final routine looked like this:

```
Date.prototype.addDaysToDate = function (days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + (days * 1)); // coerce days to be an int
    return date;
}
function updateModel() {
    var option = document.getElementById("selExpirationPeriod");
    var selectedDay = option.options[option.selectedIndex].value;
    var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);   // remove the time portion

    var expireDate = date.addDaysToDate(selectedDay);
    document.getElementById("ExpirationDate").value = expireDate;
    return true;
}
```